# JS why FOR LOOP not iterating when condition is A&&B but works when B&&A (A==B==true)

Tags: javascript, loops, logical-operators

This is my first question so hello everyone!

I wanted to write condition in way to terminate loop ASAP.

Loop which doesn`t work but should terminate loop faster:

```
for (
      let i = 0;
      transactionsSortedByTime[i].unixTime <= unixEndTime && i < listLength;
      i++
    ) {}
```

Loop which works:

```
for (
      let i = 0;
       i < listLength && transactionsSortedByTime[i].unixTime <= unixEndTime;
      i++
    ) {}
```

Till now I was certain that results of A&&B and B&&A are the same but terminates with false result in different time (when one of them {A or B} is false).

My question is why second one loop iterates properly while first one doesn`t.

Comment: When `i` is *not* less than `listLength`  you're beyond the end of the array, so accessing an element gets you `undefined`.

Comment: Did you try wrapping your conditions within a `( )` ?

Comment: Imho a `if (transactionsSortedByTime[i].unixTime > unixEndTime) { break; }` in the body of the loop would be more readable.

Comment: In logic, AND and OR are commutative (can be reordered without change in meaning), but in computation, compilers take shortcuts to skip execution when the logical result of an expression can be known before finishing the evaluation.  If A is false, then most programming languages will skip evaluating the rest of A && B && C && D.   This means, if D has a side-effect (like an exception because we're past the end of the loop), the side-effect won't be felt if A is false.  (same if A is true in A || B ||  C ...)

Comment: `i < listLength` acts as a guard in the second case, while the former one gets evaluated with a 'past array length' iterator causing exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `A & B` is not same as `B & A` because in first code snippet, you are accessing the `i'th` index of `transactionsSortedByTime` array before checking if `i` is less then `listLength`. Doing this will give you undefined when `i < listLength` is false.

So `i < listLength` should be written before `transactionsSortedByTime[i].unixTime <= unixEndTime` to make sure your code doesn't tries to access an index that is out of bounds of the `transactionsSortedByTime` array.

Answer (score -2):

Just add (), the loop structure apparently takes the bool value of the first expression, to solve this you must add parentheses, so that your expression takes the value of your && operator:

```
for (
  let i = 0;
  (transactionsSortedByTime[i].unixTime <= unixEndTime && i < listLength);
  i++
) {}
```

Comment: *"takes the bool value of the first expression"*. That includes the `&&` operator